# Ajax-jquery update of WebGrid in ASP.net web pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webgrid, razor-2

I have a grid and a form in an ASP.NET web page (Razor v2 not ASP.net Web Forms). I have written a query to retrieve data from the database and used `WebGrid` to display the data in a grid format. For the form, I have used jQuery to insert the form data into the database table. Now what I want to do is - I want to refresh only the grid (partial refresh not full) once I click on the form submit button. Any idea how to do it?